# VB.Net DataGridView change makes DataSource change

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, dataset, datasource

I have some WinForms with DGVs. The last one I created has a different behavior.
The others fill the tables with data imported via SQL query while this one fills importing json data from files. IN THEORY there would be no difference since they all set a DataTable content and then the DGV sets the DataSource with that DataTable.

Problem is this one table changes the DataSource when I change the DGV values. I could find no explanation nor solution for this but I ask you this: can this behavior be due to the other tables being imported from a DataSet->DataTable? This one does not use a DataSet. All these tables do NOT have bindings, just to be precise.

Comment: *"one table changes the DataSource when I change the DGV values"*. What does that actually mean? Are you saying that the value of the `DataSource` property changes or that the contents of the `DataTable` you assign to the `DataSource` changes? If you mean the latter then that's exactly what should happen, so I don't know what you're actually complaining about. *"All these tables do NOT have bindings"*. I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I meant the latter. I can't explain better than this since I'm new to this. As for DataSource, you're asking as if DataSource were an object of his own, while I always assumed the purpose of DataSource is being some "transfer property", like "Transfer to DGV table all that's inside the DataTable content". So basically, I always treated DataSource more like an abstract property rather than an object with actual content. About binding, I know if you use binding for the DGV you can make the values synch-ly change in both DGV and DataTable when you change either one but I'm not using that at all.

Comment: Setting the `DataSource` IS binding. I suspect that you are thinking about data-binding in the form designer as being something different to binding in code. It's not. It'[s possible to configure one-way data-binding but that's not happening if you assign a `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`. It's a two-way street. Any changes you make in the table will be reflected in the grid and vice versa. That's how it works and that's how it's supposed to work. That way, the user can edit the data and you can save the changes directly from the `DataTable`.

Comment: If you want to bind the data to the grid but don't want changes to affect the original table, call `Copy` to create a second `DataTable` and bind that.

Comment: If none of the above resolves this, please post a sample of your code showing where you assign your data source, how you create your datatable, and the contents of the data sources themselves (redacted if needed) and their structures.

Comment: Now I realize why this happen maybe. This DGV gets data from a DataTable that is globally used by the form. The other tables generally all seem to use a DataTable that is only generated inside a method to create the data but then that DataTable is kinda disposed of, I suppose, so basically it could never happen in the first place that any of those DataTables could change, I suppose. Still, you taught me something new, so thank you!

Comment: The DataTables are not disposed of. They still exist and they are bound to the grids. It's just that you don't have another reference by which to access them and see that they're changing. If you did assign the same DataTable to another variable and use that to examine the contents, you'll see they reflect any and all changes you made through the grid.

Comment: In fact this is what I did for this last DGV, i tried to check directly the DT values and they changed.

Comment: You don't even need another variable. As I said, the DataTables are still assigned to the DataSource properties so you can access them via that. That property is type Object so you would need to cast as type DataTable.